# Get Music Duration stored in Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using MusicProerties to get music duration, but it throws exception.

```
StorageFolder localRoot = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFolder mp3 = await localRoot.GetFolderAsync(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileFullPath));
StorageFile file = await mp3.GetFileAsync(Path.GetFileName(fileFullPath));
Windows.Storage.FileProperties.MusicProperties music = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync(); //Exception is thrown here

double duration = music.Duration.TotalSeconds;
```

The exception is:

```
{System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at Windows.Storage.StorageFile.get_Properties()
```

I am afraid if this is not supported in windows phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right - this API as [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.storage.storagefile.properties.aspx) is not implemented yet:

> Windows Phone 8
>
> This API is not implemented and will throw an exception if called. See Windows Phone Runtime API.

AFAIK for now there is no simple method to get duration from audio file properties,